# How to hide certain pages from search engines?

Tags: html, seo

I've got a couple of webpages that I'd like to remove from the Google search engine (error.html, sent.html etc)

I've tried using a robots.txt file, but that removed everything from the Google search engine, I must've done something wrong. The only pages that should be shown on search engines are the index page and other important pages. I've also read something about

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

but I doubt that's everything that I have to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [seo questions are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is:

Place the following meta tag into the  section of your page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="no index">
```

You can read more [Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en)